How to publish multi platform python package
For our projects we need our own developped python package but it's currently compiled only for python 3.7. For many reason we would like to bypass this restriction and use it with any >=3.7 python version. The problem is that it is a fork of a pypi library. As one of my package is dependant of it's specific version we created I specified the version in install_requires.
I tried recompiling this package with python 3.12 for example and I get :
package-1.5.2-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl and when I try to publish it on azure devops feed we are using, I get a message saying that this version of this module already exists.
Is there any way to package multiple .whl files under one specific version ? It seems possible as it is on pypi but I did not succeed achieving it. For example :
Example showing multiple whl for 1 version

Try to migrate to poetry, and then publishing packages can be rather simple with poetry publish. Many unnecessary details will be transparent to you.

The pypi screenshot shows one Source Distribution and multiple wheels(link).
I tried to follow your step to recompile the package with new name and version, then publish them together, it is successful on my side, but it shows two different packages on DevOps feed as below:

Hence, i'm afraid directly publish to devops feed with mutiple wheels(whl) in one version is not supported.
As a workaround, you can try to publish to pypi firstly(with multiples whl), then consume the pacakge on DevOps, it will fetch the package to your feed. It will have multiple wheels with one version then：


I never published anything to pypi is there an option to publish multiples whl or specifying dist/* is sufficient ?

I hope it's not the only way to do this but I'm really thankful for your solution ^^

You are welcome. You could use tox, or cibuildwheel to build different platform wheels and then publish dist/*. then in devops, you can consume the package to fetch it to feed as the workaround.
